# How to properly install Pipenv on WSL Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04, pip

I know this sounds like a pretty basic question but i've been frustrating myself to no end for the better part of a day. Am trying to set up a python environment in Windows Subsystem for Linux and everything seems to break when I install pipenv.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 from windows store
2. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
3. `sudo apt install python3-pip`
4. `pip3 install --user pipenv`

Pip outputs everything i would expect, no errors, looks like pipenv is installed.

if I try use pipenv i get `pipenv: command not found` even though my local bin is in my PATH

worse than that though, pip is now broken and attempting to use pip gives me the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

So it seems like the pipenv installation ruined the system pip by trying to install its own. I thought the `--user` flag would have avoided that but anyways am stuck, any help appreciated.

Comment: The ImportError you get, it's not because of pipenv. It's caused by `pip` upgrading from 9.0 to 19+. I can reproduce it 100% of the time..

Answer (score 5):

If [`pipenv` installed](https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/install/) successfully there will be a short notice like this:

> The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in '~/.local/bin'
>   which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if
>   you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.pipenv.org/en/latest/install/):

> This does a user installation to prevent breaking any system-wide
>   packages. If pipenv isn’t available in your shell after installation,
>   you’ll need to add the user base’s binary directory to your PATH.
>
> On Linux and macOS you can find the user base binary directory by
>   running python -m site --user-base and adding bin to the end. For
>   example, this will typically print ~/.local (with ~ expanded to the
>   absolute path to your home directory) so you’ll need to add
>   ~/.local/bin to your PATH. You can set your PATH permanently by
>   modifying ~/.profile.

Follow this:

- Open `~/.profile` file.
- Check if `~/.local/bin` path exist in that file.
- If not add these following lines

```bash
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

- Run `bash --login` for login mode because `~/.profile` is executed for login shells.
- Optionally, add those lines in `~/.bashrc` for non login shell.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me when I want to [install a python package globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41352413/13001393) into `/usr/local/bin/`.

```bsh
sudo -H pip3 install pipenv
```

If you are looking at installing it globally for the user, follow the [method in the documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#installing-pipenv):

```bsh
pip3 install --user pipenv
```

Here is where I installed globally on a Ubuntu 18.0.4 machine:

```bsh
$ sudo -H pip3 install pipenv
Collecting pipenv
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/13/b4/3ffa55f77161cff9a5220f162670f7c5eb00df52e00939e203f601b0f579/pipenv-2018.11.26-py3-none-any.whl (5.2MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.2MB 279kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=9.0.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from pipenv)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pipenv)
Installing collected packages: pipenv
Successfully installed pipenv-2018.11.26
$ which pipenv
/usr/local/bin/pipenv
$ pipenv --version
pipenv, version 2018.11.26
```

Answer (score 1):

We ran into issues just like you did. You may try the following, since it works for us:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

Don´t upgrade yet, takes longer.

Edit ~/.profile, like Biswapriyo´s answer above. Ours, we add:

```
# Add home user directory to path
export PATH="/home/$USER/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Then proceed with the commands below:

```
$ sudo apt install python3.7 python3-pip -y
$ python3.7 -m pip install --user pip
$ python3.7 -m pip install --user pipenv
```

Then, we run commands like this:

```
$ python3.7 -m pipenv check
```

[image: python3.7 -m pipenv check]

UPDATE:
You can also use it like this:

```
$pipenv check --python=`which python3.7`
```

Found this answer at [2018.11.26: pipenv emits pythons errors when creating a virtualenv #3363](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3363)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, logout/login after `pipenv` installation helped - this will apply PATH changes in .profile file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used ZSH in Ubuntu WSL. I had to add the $HOME/.local/bin to the PATH in ~/.zshrc and restart my session

Answer (score 0):

## Install Pipenv

### for Python3:

```
python3 -m pip install --user pipenv
```

### or for python2:

```
python -m pip install --user pipenv
```

The scripts pipenv and pipenv-resolver are installed in `/home/<username>/.local/bin` which is not on PATH

### Add `~/.local/bin` to PATH

```
echo 'export PATH="${HOME}/.local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

After that you will be able to create your own isolated python environment. Go inside your project folder, let's suppose it's called `python-helloworld`:

```
pipenv shell
```

You will receive a message like:

> ✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
> Virtualenv location: /home//.local/share/virtualenvs/python-helloworld-Bn_pnRzN